# Compress a PNG image with ImageMagick

Tags: php, image-processing, compression, imagemagick

To compress a JPEG image, I can do:

```
$thumb = new Imagick();
$thumb->readImage("url");
$thumb->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$thumb->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
```

However, I need to also compress PNG images (preserving alpha transparency) to keep sizes down. Is there a way to do it with ImageMagick?

Comment: PNG images are implicitly compressed. Any specific code or result deviation you want to let on?

Comment: Implicitly compressed? Not sure what you mean.. I understand that the compression is different in some way though.

Comment: You can raise the zlib compression level, but that doesn't usually effect output size much.

Comment: What @mario meant was that PNG files are _already_ compressed. There's no need (nor is it very efficient) to compress them any further.

Comment: Then what is https://pngquant.org/ - and how does it compress them so much?

Comment: @frosty basically pngquant reduces number of colors in PNG file. The standard settings will get 24bpp image reduced to 8bpp. Lower bits per pixel means much less data to compress.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pngquant` effectively quantizes, or reduces the number of colours in an image till just before there is a discernible drop in quality. You can try something similar in ImageMagick like this...

First, using the built-in `rose:` image, check the number of colours in the image - it is 3,019:

```
convert rose: -format %k info:
3019
```

and make a `PNG` of it and check the size - it is 6,975 bytes

```
convert rose: rose.png
ls -l rose.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  6975  5 Sep 20:57 rose.png
```

[image]

Now convert the rose to 255 colours and check the size - it is down to 3,691 bytes:

```
convert rose: -colors 255 rose255.png
ls -l rose255.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff   3691  5 Sep 21:02 rose255.png
```

[image]

Now convert the rose to 64 colours and check the size - down to 2,361 bytes

```
convert rose: -colors 64 rose64.png
ls -l rose64.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  2361  5 Sep 21:04 rose64.png
```

[image]

Another way of optimising or reducing PNG filesizes is to use `-strip` to strip out any metadata from images - such as the date and time the picture was taken, the camera and lens model, the name of the program that created the image and the copyright and colour profiles.

Also, worth bearing in mind... normally, the colour of transparent pixels is irrelevant because you can't see them, but uniform things generally compress better. So, it may be a good idea to make all transparent pixels the same colour when saving PNG files, by using `-alpha background`.

**Example**

```
convert -size 512x512 xc:gray +noise random a.png                                      # create an image of random noise
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  1576107  6 Sep 11:37 a.png                                  # 157kB

convert -size 512x512 xc:gray +noise random -alpha transparent a.png                   # recreate but make transparent
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  1793567  6 Sep 11:38 a.png                                  # 179kB, extra transparency channel

convert -size 512x512 xc:gray +noise random -alpha transparent -alpha background a.png # make all transparent pixels black
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  1812  6 Sep 11:38 a.png                                     # Presto!
```

Comment: How do I do this in ImageMagick?

Comment: `convert` **IS** ImageMagick.

Comment: Oh, sorry. So can I do, `convert http://example.com/image.png: -format %k info`? or?

Comment: I don't really understand how to do this with PHP.. can you make an example using `http://example.com/image.png`? Thank you. For reference here's what I mean: http://puu.sh/k1a67/0dd24b43e7.png

Comment: I don't speak much PHP but you can either call `exec('convert ...');` or use something like `$Image=new Imagick( "http://..." );$num_colors = $image->getImageColors();`

Comment: `exec('convert http://example.com/image.png -colors 255 test.png');` works like a charm, saving it as `test.png` in the root folder

Comment: As a follow up, how does pngquant determine the 'just before loss of quality'? So for example if an image has 5000 colours, does it do like 25% of that? Is there a general rule of thumb?

Comment: The crux of it is how it does the median cut - you can read the relevant source and see the reference to the SIGGRAPH paper here... https://github.com/pornel/pngquant/blob/master/lib/mediancut.c

Comment: Having said that the question was related to PHP and not command line, this answer should clarify why the PHP Imagick does not fit the job.

Comment: What exactly does `-alpha background` do? When I experiment with that, instead of getting a black background (but with transparent pixels!), all that happens is that I get an empty, broken PNG. Or is that option only for greyscale?...

Answer (score 2):

Setting grayscale with `-set colorspace Gray` won't reduce the PNG's file-size unless these options are also used:

```
-define png:compression-level=9 -define png:format=8 -define png:color-type=0 -define png:bit-depth=8
```

This makes 8-bit grayscale with highest PNG compression. Adding those options reduced my image size 3×, because now it's one channel (grayscale) whereas before it was 3 (RGB).