# ImageMagick: How to not save background color information?

Tags: image, imagemagick, png, transparency, image-editing

How - if at all - is it possible to create a fully transparent image with ImageMagick?

The problem: It's always getting a background color, white by default (as per docs)

More specifically, looking for: Not even a single background color stored in the file, so that every viewer that supports PNG will see it as a fully transparent image - just like the input

My commandline is:

`magick convert in.png -trim out.png`

Comment: See also the example at the end of this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32417234/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard "transparent" is a zero valued alpha channel over a black background, so rgba(0,0,0,0). If you want to ensure such, then make the background black under the transparent areas. So for example from your command assuming in.png has some transparency:

```
magick in.png -background black -alpha background -trim +repage out.png
```

Note that in ImageMagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.

Comment: Hm, that is already a good hint incase there's nothing better, but if I open that in Picasa Photo Viewer (for example) it shows a black background and no transparent (like it does in image editors)

If I save it with [this feature](http://justpic.info/images4/29b3/2020032415_13_18ExportImageasPNG.png) in Gimp, it's displayed correctly (though the output is then also more than 3 times larger):

Comment: When you use -trim and save to PNG, you should add +repage to remove the virtual canvas. Otherwise the image will still display with the part you trimmed off. I have added that to may command above. See the command above and try that again with the +repage added before saving to PNG